# NCl₃ + H₂O → NH₃ + HOCl , the resulting solution is acidic, basic or neutral?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

When $\ce{NCl3}$ is dissolved in water, $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{HOCl}$ is formed.

Can you please explain me whether formed solution is acid or basic or neutral? thank you!

Comment: Try balancing the equation. What do you notice?

Comment: You should specify initial concentrations. generally, your question has no simple 'qualitative' answer, as both acid and base produced are weak. However, analytical chemistry textbooks should have an entire  section about calculation of pH of similar solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Here's our initial reaction, $$\ce{NCl3 + 3H2O -> NH3 + 3HOCl}$$ $\ce{NH3}$ is a weak base and $\ce{HOCl}$ is a weak acid, but there is more of the acid, so at this point the solution would be mildly acidic. However $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{HOCl}$ are known to react as follows $$\ce{NH3 + HOCl->NH2Cl + H2O}$$ and in aqueous solution the resultant chloramine can decompose as shown in the following equation $$\ce{3 NH2Cl ⟶ N2 + NH4Cl + 2 HCl}$$  Clearly, an acid is generated in this last reaction.  So although the initial products are neutral, eventually the solution will be strongly acidic.

Comment: What's the extent of these reactions?

Comment: I suspect they all move further to the right with time - the ammonia escapes or is consumed, the chloramine decomposes or reacts further, just a guess.  Open or closed containers would make a difference in the rates.

Comment: I was wondering because the extents can affect whether the solution is actually mildly acidic, strongly acidic, or not acidic at all. Strongly acidic implies that the third reaction goes forward to a large extent.

Comment: Good point.  But you'd be a tough professor.  The OP's teacher just wanted to know acidic, basic or neutral; you're drilling down to not, mildly or strongly acidic :) I would guess that the third reaction goes far to the right as the nitrogen leaves the liquid phase, just don't know the timescale.

Comment: What about this reaction? NH3 + HOCl -> NH4+ + ClO-? This reaction would be large extent, and would probably consume a fair bit of the ammonia and hypochlorous acid.

Comment: K for aforementioned reaction is 52 btw.

Comment: Since you give a K value, I assume its an equilibrium.  Since the product doesn't react further, it will revert to reactant as the ammonia is siphoned off in other reactions.  See problem 4 (scroll down to the answers) at https://engineering.purdue.edu/~jafvert/ce%20554/CE%2059700%20008%20S2010%20HW%204.pdf  Looks like the reaction shown above is the major pathway for $\ce{NH3 + HOCl}$

Comment: Aren't all chemical reactions in equilibrium at least to some extent? Also, you can get the K value easily. K for the reaction = Ka(reactant acid)/Ka(conjugate acid).

Comment: Yes, at least to some extent.

Comment: @ron no that can;t be. My teacher explained me the correct answer.Your answer is wrong. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @YomalSamindu It would be helpful if you posted the correct answer.

Comment: @YomalSamindu So, what is the correct answer? Can you at least shortly explain it here in a comment?

Comment: @YomalSamindu As the others say , it would be nice if you give your perception over here in the comments or as an answer .

Answer (score 0):

It is less but acidic since in HOCl, OH bond dissociates to form proton.Though NH3 is a lewis base,it is not  strong enough to neutralize the acidic HOCl.

Comment: Consider coming over [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-‌​and-random-talk). You might be interested since there are Indian highschool students out there.